# Why Next() doesn't work. when I post using my frontend

Tags: node.js, flutter, express

I am developing an app: flutter for frontend and ExpressJS + NodeJS for backEnd. I use JWT to create authentication system. I have a middleware function "verifyJWT", which is invoked when i try to reach data/****. The problem is when i use postman to create post request to auth/userdata - everything is ok. But when i try to do the same thing using my frontend, it seems that i am only able to reach "verifyJWT". I get an error:"Cannot POST /userdata"

BACKEND CODE:

verifyJWT.js

```
`const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();
const verifyJWT = (req, res, next) =>{
    console.log("verifying")

    const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];

    if (!authHeader) return res.sendStatus(401);
    console.log(authHeader)
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(
        token,
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        (error,decoded) =>{
            if(error) return res.sendStatus(403);
            req.email = decoded.email;
            console.log(req.email)
            console.log("ready to next")
            next()
        }
    )
}`
```

app.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'25mb'}));
app.use(cookieParser());



//not protected routers
app.use('/auth', AuthRouter);
app.use('/refresh', RefreshRouter );

//protected by jwt_token
app.use(verifyJWT);
app.use('/data', DataRouter);
app.use('/portfolio', DiplomaRouter);
```

data.router.js

```
`//GENERAL DATA OPERATIONS
router.post('/userdata',  UserController.userdata)
router.post('/updateUserData', UserController.updateUserData)
router.post("/usersBySchool", UserController.getUsersListBySchool)
router.post("/usersByCity", UserController.getUsersListByCity)
router.post("/getPopulation", SchoolController.getPopulation)
```

userdata from usercontroller.js

```
const userdata =  async(req, res) => {
    try{
        console.log("getting data")
        const data = await UserService.getUserData(req.email)
        console.log(data)
        res.json(data)

    }catch (error){
        console.log("Something went wrong with retrieving userdata: " + error);
    }
}`
```

FRONTEND CODE:

```
`getUserData(String email, String token) async{
 var reqBody = {
   "email" : email,
 };
 try{
   var responce = await http.post(Uri.parse(userdata),
       headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json",
                 "authorization": "Bearer $token",
                
       },
       body: jsonEncode(reqBody)).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));


   var jsonResponse = await jsonDecode(responce.body);
   print(jsonResponse);
   return jsonResponse;

 } on TimeoutException catch (error){
   print("nothing");
   return 0;
 }`
```

It seems that i missed or misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad, I should use:

```js
return next()
```

Instead of:

```js
next()
```